# How can I use a Google Chrome extension with Selenium?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape match information from the a page like this one (page is in the same format, but obviously has different values for different matches): https://csgolounge.com/match?m=8967

The problem is, the information that I want is only displayed if you are using the Chrome extension, "Lounge Destroyer"... After tons of trial and error, I finally figured out that in order to get that information, the python script I use has to have that extension "included in it" somehow. I have browsed other answers here and found this code from a different stackoverflow thread that demonstrates how to add an extension when using selenium:

```
            from selenium import webdriver
            from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

            chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chop.add_extension('Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chop)
```

I went to [Chrome Extension Downloader](http://chrome-extension-downloader.com/) to snag the .crx file for LoungeDestroyer, placed it in the chrome extension folder (getting the file address from "Get Info"), and modified the above code a little bit for my purposes to get the following:

```
            from selenium import webdriver
            from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

            chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chop.add_extension('Users/Username_Here/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/ghahcnmfjfckcedfajbhekgknjdplfcl/LoungeDestroyer_v0.9.3.7.crx')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options = chop)

            matchID = raw_input("Enter match ID (four digit number in CSGL URL): ")
            driver.get("https://csgolounge.com/match?m="+matchID)
```

The problem is, I don't think I've substituted the right thing where the 'Adblock-Plus_v1.4.1.crx' was in the original code.

Running my modified version returns the following error:

```
            IOError: Path to the extension doesn't exist
```

Any help or advice is greatly, greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that I didn't have chromedriver installed (http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=2.21/). After installing that, I had to enter the path to the chromedriver executable in my code. All said and done, this was the code that worked:

```
            from selenium import webdriver
            from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options


            chop = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            chop.add_extension('/Users/Username_Here/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/Extensions/ghahcnmfjfckcedfajbhekgknjdplfcl/LoungeDestroyer_v0.9.3.7.crx')
            driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/Username_Here/Downloads/chromedriver', chrome_options = chop)

            # go to the match page
            matchID = raw_input("Enter match ID (four digit number in CSGL URL): ")
            driver.get("https://csgolounge.com/match?m="+matchID)
```

Also, the reason I was getting that extension-path error was because I didn't have the forward slash in front of the word "Users" in the file address.